# how to parse the listview value from one window to another in appcelerator alloy

Tags: javascript, listview, titanium-alloy

```
function handleClick(e) {
    var section = $.list.sections[e.sectionIndex];
    var item = section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    Ti.API.info(item);
    var albumWindow = Alloy.createController('albums').getView();
    $.indexWindow.openWindow(albumWindow);
}
```

hi, 
       iam retrieving set of values from a row in list view

here the "item" will display the values inside the rows once we click ... its shows the values in console .. im doing this index.js ..now i have to call this values to next window ... how can i call ?  any ideas  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data like below.

```
var albumWindow = Alloy.createController('albums', {'item': item}).getView();
```

in the `albums.js` you have to retrieve like this,

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

var items = args.item;
```